# Python graphics window not interactive with mouse

Tags: python-2.7, osx-snow-leopard

I am using the graphics.py library from the book "Python Programming" by John Zelle. For some reason on my mac, the mouse does not interact with the graphics window using this command: "win.getMouse()". When typed in the Python interpreter, the prompt ">>>" does not return and the command has to be killed with CNTRL-C. The specific problem is "triangle.py" from chapter 5.

Is there a way to fix this or use an alternative python graphics system more friendly on a mac.

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: tkinter is part of the python stdlib so you would think its pretty portable. There are definitely alternatives though but they wouldn't necessarily line up with your teaching guide.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Prof. Zelle. Download the current graphics.py file from http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ and rerun program. It works fine now.